Xcode Mac C++ vDSP_mmul returning different results
Using XCODE -std=c++17, Accelerate Framework included in the project.
vDSP_mmul(const float* Nonnull A,vDSP_Stride IA,const float* Nonnull B,vDSP_Stride IB, float *Nonnull C,vDSP_Stride IC)

Results stored in MatC didn't work out to a correct 2by4 matrix correctly.
matrixA - height stride == 3
matrixB - height stride == 4
matc - height stride = 4

Any idea what went wrong?
#include <vecLib/vDSP.h>
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>

#define XXX __asm__("nop")
float matrixA[2][3] {
    {18.237,15.213,20.393},
    {20.13,17.392,18.82}
};
float matrixB[3][4]{
    {17.145,9.32,15.238,20.763},
    {2.173,9.13,8.34,9.23},
    {1.33,8.32,15.23,6.182}
};
float matC[2][4] {
    {1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f},
    {1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f}
};
XXX;
vDSP_mmul((const float*)&matrixA[0][0],3,(const float*)&matrixB[0][0],4,(float*)&matC[0][0],4,2,3,2);
XXX;

https://i.sstatic.net/Da3Ju.jpg

Per the vDSP_mmul documentation, the argument after each address is the stride through the array. That is the number of physical elements to skip. That is used when you want a column-oriented traversal of a matrix. For ordinary operations, use a stride of 1.
The third-to-last argument is the number of rows in matrices A and C. That is 2, which you have.
The second-to-last argument is the number of columns in matrices B and C. That is 4, not the 3 you have.
You do not need to cast the addresses, because matrixA[0][0], for example, is already a float *. And you do not need to include <vecLib/vDSP.h>; including <Accelerate/Accelerate.h> suffices.
The vDSP_mmul call can be:
vDSP_mmul(
    &matrixA[0][0], 1,
    &matrixB[0][0], 1,
    &matC[0][0], 1,
    2, 4, 3);

